# Multiple AJAX forms on the same page?

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I am struggling to have multiple AJAX submitted forms on the same php page. I can get it to work with one, but when I add more, it just uses the first form all the time.
I have tried to make it unique but not sure exactly how to do this.

My code is below, if someone could please assist that would be fantastic.
I have looked at similar questions and answers on this site but can't seem to fathom how to make it work for mine.

The form should submit when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.
Thanks very much in advance for all your help.

Martyn.

**HTML form**

```
<form id="search_form" method="post">
    <input readonly type="text" name="id" value=<?php echo $row1[0];?>>
    <input readonly type="text" name="student" value=<?php echo $row1[1];?>>
    <input readonly type="text" name="addedby" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>>
    <input readonly type="text" name="register" value="monday_morning">
    <input <?php if($row1[4] == "Yes"){echo "checked";}?> type="checkbox" name="box" value="Yes">
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change", '[type="checkbox"]', function () {
        var url = "/register_update.php";
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#search_form").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's just one form though. Do you have multiple forms with `id="search_form"` on that page? Because that's invalid, `id`s need to be unique

Comment: @kerbholz I added multiple forms each with a different id and a different script to go with it that had the different id as well. It kept submitting using the first instance of the form.

Comment: So you have multiple `$(document).on("change",'[type="checkbox"]',function(){ ...` on your page? They don't "stack", changing _any_ checkbox on the page will trigger "_the first_" code

Comment: @kerbholz Yes, and each one I have changed the line `data: $("#search_form").serialize(),` to reflect the id of each form. So this is clearly the problem. How would I be able to do it with multiple forms but one script that 'catches' any of the unique form submissions?

Comment: Which doesn't matter, since only your first `$(document).on("change",'[type="checkbox"]'` gets triggered, that's why only the first form gets submitted. You'd need to be more specific in which checkboxes should trigger which form, something like `$(document).on("change",'#form1 [type="checkbox"]'` should submit form1, `$(document).on("change",'#form2 [type="checkbox"]'` should submit form2 etc. (I don't think those codes will actually work, but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. If anyone has some example script though I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change", '[type="checkbox"]', function (event) {
        var url = "/register_update.php";
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $($(event.target).parent()).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

`event.target` returns the clicked checkbox.
`parent()` function returns the form you need to submit. This way you don't need to have unique form id.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't seem to get this to work. It does not seem to be doing anything. I get this error message when I show page source: `TypeError: parent is not a function. (In 'parent(event.target)', 'parent' is an instance of Window)`

Comment: Updated. It shoud be `event.target.parent()`

Comment: I made the updates but it still is not working. Should I remove the form id's?

Comment: It's working! Thanks very much! Really appreciate it